# Difference between definitions of a random sample

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

> **Definition 5.1.1** The random variables $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ are called a random sample of size $n$ from the population $f(x)$ if $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ are mutually independent random variables and the marginal pdf or pmf of each $X_{i}$ is the same function $f(x)$. Alternatively, $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ are called independent and identically distributed random variables with pdf or pmf $f(x)$. This is commonly abbreviated to iid random variables.

What is the difference between these two definitions? Wouldn't both "random sample of size $n$ from the population" and "independent and identically distributed random variables" be the same thing? both have the same density function and are all independent.

Comment: Looks the same.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Why use the term "alternatively" then? This implies that they are different

Comment: "Alternatively" here (as I understand it) is used to indicate that you can call such family of random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ either "a random sample" or [alternatively] "i.i.d random variables".

Comment: The wording is different, but mathematically, they are equivalent.